# How to customize the appearance of eglot's inlay hint?

Tags: faces, fonts, eglot

`eglot`'s inlay hints are extremely close to the actual code, it makes the code almost unreadable. For example:

[image]

The name of field is `input`, but it looks like `inputString`!

Is it possible to customize the padding between code and inlay hints, or change the background color of inlay hints?

Comment: I guess you can use `M-x customize-face` `eglot-inlay-hint-face` to change the face.

Answer (score 1):

The format of inlay hints is determined as follows:

- inlay hints are displayed using the three faces `eglot-type-hint-face`, `eglot-parameter-hint-face`, and `eglot-inlay-hint-face`, which all inherit from `eglot-inlay-hint-face`, which you may customise;
- there is some extra padding which is added to inlay hints, but that is not customisable (it is hard-wired in `eglot--update-hints-1`).

I think it might be worthwile to file a bug with Emacs in order to make the amount of padding customisable.